# WCF Rest service Windows authentication via Browser

Tags: c#, wcf, kerberos

Given is a wcf rest service which runs with HttpClientCredentialType.Windows and enforces a user to authenticate via kerberos.

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type serviceType = typeof (AuthService);
        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(serviceType);

        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

        ServiceEndpoint basicServiceEndPoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAuthService), binding,  "http://notebook50:87");
        basicServiceEndPoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

        Console.WriteLine("wcf service started");
        serviceHost.Open();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    public List<string> GetUserInformation()
    {
        List<string> userInfo = new List<string>();
        userInfo.Add("Environment.User = " + Environment.UserName);
        userInfo.Add("Environment.UserDomain = " + Environment.UserDomainName);
        if (OperationContext.Current != null && OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext != null)
        {
            userInfo.Add("WindowsIdentity = " + OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name);
            userInfo.Add("Auth protocol = " + OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.AuthenticationType);
        }
        else
        {
            userInfo.Add("WindowsIdentity = empty");
        }
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
        return userInfo;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "test/")]
    List<string> GetUserInformation();
}
```

When i run this as a console application, and then open the website `http://notebook50:87/test/` in internet explorer from another computer, i get a 'bad request' response. 
I did enable kerberos logging, and it shows me KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED

I can solve this problem by creating a windows service, and run it under 'Local System account'. 
In this case, a client is able to authenticate.

Question: What permission/settings does a user(which runs this wcf service) need in order to get the same behavior as when the application is running as windows service under local system? 
Is this related with the Service Principle Name?

Comment: What happens if you make a shared folder on notebook50, and try to access it from your other computer ? Does it prompt for login? If you login with the login form, and then try to access http://notebook50:87/test/ does it work then ?

Comment: "Is this related with the Service Principle Name" quite possibly. My first question is WHY are you using Kerberos, I have in the past spend 2 man weeks fruitlessly debugging Kerberos (are you sure you can't use NTLM). Secondly, Kerberos requires a huge number of things to get right for it to work, one of which is that the client needs to authenticate the server...which is what the SPN is. The SPN MUST match the DNS entry you use to access the server (in this case notebook50, which is almost certainly DOES NOT, as by default , if that even happened, it would be set to the FQDN of your server).

Comment: @Magic-Mouse Sorry dude. Your comment is not helpful. This is clearly an issue with Kerberos auth.

Comment: What is the identity of the application pool which is running your application?

Comment: There is no application pool involved. It's a standalone windows service running the wcf rest service.

Comment: About the why using kerberos at all: One of our customer has multiple domain forest and connects them by giving trust, and i was told it is easier to use kerberos than ntlm in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working now. 
It really was a problem with the SPN
At the beginning, I've set the SPN like **setpn -A HTTP/notebook50.foo.com**, and with this, the kerberos authentication didn't work.

Now, i've set it like **setspn -A HTTP/notebook50.foo.com username** where username is the user under which the service runs.

From the SPN documentation i've read, it was not clear to me that i have to set the user account in this way.

It would be great if one could explain what happens here, and probably a link to a documentation for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop this error pops up via enable the "Do not require Kerberos preauthentication" option for that user account in Active directory users & computers ->  properties -> account.

Comment: I did enable this property for the user account which is running the windows service. It still doesn't work. Now the error in system log is: KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED. But as soon as i switch the user to "local system" everything works.

Comment: According with msdn specifications,KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED may occour when: 1. Mismatch DNS name resolution - The issue is very common in a NLB environment that uses a multiplies
IP's or/and multiplies network adapters.
2. The user doesn’t have a Local NTFS access permission.
3. The Web Site is using Application Pool with a poor permission settings.